# Getting new class instance as default prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form component that gets a custom class named `Experience` through props. User fills the form and component writes changes on the given class instance, then calls a function prop named `onExperienceChange`. When no experience given to component it just creates a new one. I'm using default props and I wonder if there is a way to get new class instance with default props.

What I have currently:

```
class ExperienceForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if (this.props.experience === undefined)
            this.experience = new Experience("Experience", "");
        else
            this.experience = this.props.experience;
    }
```

What I want it to be look like:

```
class ExperienceForm extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        experience = {new Experience("Experience", "")} // it has to create new Experience each time
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.experience = this.props.experience;
    }
```

Or something like this:

```
class ExperienceForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, experience = new Experience("Experience", "")) {
        super(props);

        this.experience = experience;
    }
```

This is how `Experience` class looks like:

```
class Experience {
    constructor(
        header, 
        description, 
        startDate = "",
        endDate = "",
        headerIcon = null, 
        headerDescription = "", 
        headerLink = "", 
        keywords = []) 
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.description = description;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.headerIcon = headerIcon;
        this.headerDescription = headerDescription;
        this.headerLink = headerLink;
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
const defaultProps = ()=> new Experience("Experience", "")

class ExperienceForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.experience = this.props.experience || defaultProps() ;
    }
```

A cleaner way would be:

```
class ExperienceForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
         super(props);

        this.experience = this.props.experience || new Experience("Experience","");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already aware of `or(||)` usage, but I wonder if it is possible to do with default props. Seems like it is not.

Comment: By ES2020 [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) introduced to overcome weird javascript falsy rules.